# Idiomatic Scala way of generating combinations lazily

Tags: scala, combinations

I want to generate a combination of some values as in the code below:

```
object ContinueGenerate {

  val foods = List("A", "B", "C")
  val places = List("P1", "P2", "P3")
  val communities = List("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")

  case class Combination(food: String, place: String, community: String)

  def allCombinations() = {
    for {
      food <- foods; place <- places; community <- communities
    } yield Combination(food, place, community)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    allCombinations foreach println
  }

}
```

However the problem with this approach is that, all the data is generated at once. This is big problem when the size of `foods`, `places` and `communities` becomes very large. Also there could be other parameters other than these three.

So I want to be able generate combinations, in a continuation style, such that a combination is generated only when it is requested.

What would be an idiomatic Scala way of doing that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a `View` over each list. In the code below I've added a side effect so it is visible when the `yield` gets called for each element.

```
val foods = List("A", "B", "C")
val places = List("P1", "P2", "P3")
val communities = List("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")

case class Combination(food: String, place: String, community: String)

def allCombinations() =
  for {
    food <- foods; place <- places; community <- communities
  } yield {
    val comb = Combination(food, place, community)
    println(comb)
    comb
  }

//Prints all items
val combinations = allCombinations()

def allCombinationsView() =
  for {
    //Use a view of each list
    food <- foods.view; place <- places.view; community <- communities.view
  } yield {
    val comb = Combination(food, place, community)
    println(comb)
    comb
  }
//Prints nothing
val combinationsView = allCombinationsView()

//Prints 5 items
val five = combinationsView.take(5).toList
```

Answer (score 7):

You use streams:

```
object ContinueGenerate {

  val foods = Stream("A", "B", "C")
  val places = Stream("P1", "P2", "P3")
  val communities = Stream("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")

  case class Combination(food: String, place: String, community: String)

  def allCombinations() = {
    for {
      food <- foods; place <- places; community <- communities
    } yield Combination(food, place, community)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    allCombinations foreach println
  }

}
```

A `Stream` caches all the data. If you only want to iterate once, use `Iterator` instead, which should garbage-collect already traversed elements.